# RxJS with .NET web api data streaming

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, rxjs

Background: I have a background with Angular and .NET and am learning RxJS right now.  I have successfully put together a notification module that leverages SignalR and RxJS to handle system notifications to a user and I LOVE how easy it is to work with.

Question: I currently have a web api call that queries multiple sources in individual Task calls and then merges them into one dataset to be sent back to the client.  This call doesn't take too long right now because of few sources and the sources themselves have sample data in them. But I imagine that once I start tying real data in, that this call could take a really long time.  I'd like to find a way to configure my web api so that I could pass back an open stream of data that would be monitored by RxJS to display data as it comes in. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It is a whole lot easier to help if we can see what you have tried so far =).

Comment: I haven't actually tried anything yet because I have no idea how to do it on both ends.  I'm not looking for actual code, I'm trying to learn how to stream data back from the sql db, to the api, to the client.  SignalR is supposed to be lightweight messaging so it worked for my notification module so that solution won't work for data streaming back hundreds/thousands of records.  I know that I need to learn how to setup a stream between SQL and the webapi.  After that I know I need to setup an rxjs observable on the call to the webapi so that as data comes back I can process it.

Comment: To expand on what I said above, with my current knowledge of. Net, I would open a sqlreader to get data and then while reading the results I would response.write the answer back.  But this wouldn't necessarily work with multiple sources unless I keep updating my code every time I add/remove a source.  I should be able to store connection information of sources in a db, create async Tasks for each source and then stream data back to an Rx observable that scrubs  the data before publishing it to a subscriber.  Does that help explaining there issue I'm having?

Comment: Your question seems too broad, and requires many pieces to be connected together which would make it probably a difficult fit for this Q&A format. I would recommend you divide your issue in smaller pieces and ask questions of a smaller scope separately. You already identified an approach, try to implement it and ask questions on the specific issues that you are faced with.

Comment: First question could be how to setup a stream between SQL and a webapi, which already is a broad question that you would have to precise - are you talking about continuous (realtime) query? Do you have a choice on the database, or what are your constraints at this level? Is there a way with your database to return the result of a long query bit by bit (cursor?) Or is it enough that each queried data source sends directly its result when ready, without waiting for all of them to return to consolidate in one big dataset? You could remove the angularjs and rxjs tags and add some database tags

Comment: Second question could be, now that you have your stream of data from database to web server/API working, how to stream it to the client. You could give details of your web APIs and your constraints there (http only? can you use sockets? server-side events? etc.). Again no angularjs tag here Your problem here seems to be more about client/server or comunication protocol between API consumer and API producer. Third question could be on the client side how to package the incoming data streams and process it. That could be a Rxjs/Angular problem, with the corresponding tags set in your question.

Comment: Separate your concerns, separate your questions, tag appropriately to address the right audience, do some research on each question, try some approach and show what you have found by yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I realize how broad the question is now.  I'll do more research and come back with more refined questions